# HTML image not loading the image src

Tags: html, reactjs, web

Hey guys I'm making a TodoApp in react js, and I have a simple layout and I wanted to add a few images to the app. But when I add the images it is not loading that image.

Here is the code

```
import TodoList from './components/TodoList';
import imagem from './skate.png'


function App() {
  return (
    
    <div className="todo-app">
        <TodoList />
        <img src="imagem"/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And here is an image of what´s happening:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So,
In React.js (jsx) things don't work quite like HTML. WHat you are doing is importing the image from its location, by using:
import image from './skate.png';

and then, inside of your function.
If you import anything (image, css file, json file), for you to be able to use it you need to call it.

for example:

import JsonData from './data.json'

```
function App(){
return(
  <div>
    <JsonData/>
  </div>
)
```

}

To call it.
SO in you case, you just need to replace 
to

and it should work.

Comment: No, the imported image is not a component, and not would imported JSON.

Answer (score 4):

When using an bundler (like Parcel or Webpack) to handle images, you need to remember that the imported value is a **variable**.

You pass variables to props with `{` and `}`. Using a pair of `"` gives you a hardcoded string.

```
    <img src={imagem} />
```

Comment: Ty so much. So if i used a website link i used "" instead {} is that?

Comment: If you wanted to pass a hard coded string with a URL in it then you would use `"` and `"`.

Comment: hmm okok make sense

Answer (score 2):

How about if you do this:

`<img src={imagem} />`

otherwise, it gets interpreted as a string and you have no http://../imagen on your site.

Comment: oh ok makes sense Ty so much, I'm new at this

Comment: Those things get more obvious as you do more react. Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that

```
"imagem"
```

is read as a String. To read it as an image, place {} around it as so:

```
{imagem}
```

Comment: oh ok! make sense ty

Comment: No problem! I love the design of your website :)

Comment: ahahah ty so much <3

Answer (score 1):

`"imagem"` is string. Need variable `{imagem]`.

Comment: oh ok make sense, ty I'm new at this <3

Answer (score 1):

when you use qoutes `""` in jsx, it consumes it as a string and when you use `{}`, it consumes it as normal JS, so in your case, if you use

```
<img src={imagem} />
```

that would solve your problem